# Is my understanding of "select distinct" correct?

Tags: sql, select, db2, performance, distinct

We recently discovered a performance problem with one of our systems and I think I have the fix but I'm not certain my understanding is correct.

In simplest form, we have a table `blah` into which we accumulate various values based on a key field. The basic form is:

```
recdate   date
rectime   time
system    varchar(20)
count     integer
accum1    integer
accum2    integer
```

There are a lot more accumulators than that but they're all of the same form. The primary key is made up of `recdate`, `rectime` and `system`.

As values are collected to the table, the count for a given `recdate/rectime/system` is incremented and the values for that key are added to the accumulators. That means the averages can be obtained by using `accumN / count`.

Now we also have a view over that table specified as follows:

```
create view blah_v (
    recdate, rectime, system, count,
    accum1,
    accum2
) as select distinct
    recdate, rectime, system, count,
    value (case when count > 0 then accum1 / count end, 0),
    value (case when count > 0 then accum2 / count end, 0)
    from blah;
```

In other words, the view gives us the average value of the accumulators rather than the sums. It also makes sure we don't get a divide-by-zero in those cases where the count is zero (these records *do* exist and we are not allowed to remove them so don't bother telling me they're rubbish - you're preaching to the choir).

We've noticed that the time difference between doing:

```
select distinct recdate from XX
```

varies greatly depending on whether we use the table or the view. I'm talking about the difference being 1 second for the table and 27 seconds for the view (with 100K rows).

We actually tracked it back to the `select distinct`. What seems to be happening is that the DBMS is actually loading all the rows in and sorting them so as to remove duplicates. That's fair enough, it's what we stupidly told it to do.

But I'm pretty sure the fact that the view includes every component of the primary key means that it's impossible to have duplicates anyway. We've validated the problem since, if we create another view without the distinct, it performs at the same speed as the underlying table.

I just wanted to confirm my understanding that a `select distinct` can not have duplicates if it includes all the primary key components. If that's so, then we can simply change the view appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's no point in asking for `distinct` results when all the primary key elements are included.

The table's primary key constraint already precludes duplicates across those columns, but your DBMS will still process the tuples to ensure they are distinct.

Answer (score 4):

In this case the DISTINCT isn't doing you any good because your distinct fields are already guaranteed to be unique because of the PRIMARY KEY constraint on the underlying table.  You might try rewriting the view as:

```
create view blah_v ( 
    recdate, rectime, system, count, 
    accum1, 
    accum2 
) as select
       recdate, rectime, system, count, 
       case when count > 0 then accum1 / count else 0 end,
       case when count > 0 then accum2 / count else 0 end,
       from blah;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

If the view is selecting directly from a single table and a subset of selected columns are unique on the table then it follows that the selected rows would be unique in values and distinct is redundant.